# How to execute a single method and passing list of value concurrently

Tags: multithreading, list, concurrency

Suppose I have a List which have 2000 values, i want to divide the list of values and and passing to the method concurrently, SO I can increase my performance.
I applied bellow multi thread concept but its also taking 10 Minutes

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < visitList.size()/2; i = i + 2) {
                auditedT1 += accuracyDao.SumOfChartsAudited(visitList.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < visitList.size()/2; i = i + 2) {
                auditedT2 += accuracyDao.SumOfChartsAudited(visitList.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            for (int i = visitList.size()/2; i < visitList.size(); i = i + 2) {
                auditedT3 += accuracyDao.SumOfChartsAudited(visitList.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            for (int i = visitList.size()/2+1; i < visitList.size(); i = i + 2) {
                auditedT4 += accuracyDao.SumOfChartsAudited(visitList.get(i));
            }
        }
    });

t.start();
    t1.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t.join();
    t1.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your main question, check out java parallel streams. It's only one way to do this but it's fairly straightforward. You can use a map operation to perform the database calls, then a collect to sum them all together.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

There is no guarantee that this will improve performance though. You may have to profile and see where the performance issue really lies. It could be in your database, network, or somewhere else. (assuming you're using a database since there's DAO in your method names)